# How can request params be validated to ensure they include required params and don’t include unsupported params?

Tags: ruby, api, sinatra

This is particularly in the context of a `REST` API built with `Ruby` and `Sinatra`.

It's easy enough to manually check to make sure that the required params are not nil. And it's easy to iterate through a flat params hash to see if it's allowed in a whitelist.

However, when the params hash also include hashes it becomes more difficult.

One way of handling this I've thought of is converting the params hash to `JSON` and using a library to validate it against a `JSON` schema.

I have come across the [sinatra-param](https://github.com/mattt/sinatra-param) gem but I haven't had a chance to see if it can validate sub-hashes or check for unsupported params.

**Edit:** Another possible way, that might make more sense is passing params directly to the model (I'm  using DataMapper) and using its validation and errors instead of rewriting validations.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/nateware/sinatra-accept-params too, although if either/none of these libraries don't quite do what you want, your tests could easily become specs and a pull request (hint, hint;)

Answer (score 1):

If each of your routes are going to take the same 4 params (IE `:one, :two, :three, :four`), you could set up a before filter, store an array of those four params as an instance variable in the before (which is accessible to all routes) and use a sexy little method from class Enumerable called `all?`:

```
before do
  @base_params = [params[:one], params[:two], params[:three], params[:four]]

  unless @base_params.all?
    redirect '/error_route'
  end
end
```

`Enumerable#all?` will return true only if all values in your 'collection' are not `false` or `nil`. Documentation can be found [here for Ruby 1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

Additionally if you find that you have different sets of params, you can create a hash instead of just an array of @base_params where they keys are the string value of request.request_method:

```
before do

  @base_params = {"GET"  => [params[:one], params[:two], params[:three], params[:four]], 
                  "POST" => [params[:five], params[:six], params[:seven]],
                  "PUT"  => [params[:one], params[:five], params[:six]]}

  unless @base_params[request.request_method].all?
    redirect '/error_route'
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, only the `POST` and `PUT` routes take the same params so using the before route won't work. `Enumerable#all?` is indeed a beautiful thing though.

Comment: @JordanY. you could use the filter with a conditional check of [the request verbs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object) e.g. `if request.post? || request.put?`

Comment: @iain Good point, I some how overlooked that. But still, this solution only covers half the answer so I can't accept it.

Comment: @JordanY. can you post up an example of the kind of params you're worried about?

Comment: Well you could just take it a step further and have a hash of params, where the keys specify if the request is a POST, PUT, GET, etc and the values are the params. I will update the answer.